# Getting error with trunc function for determining age

Tags: sql, oracle

I am fairly new to using oracle SQL. I am trying to use the `TRUNC` function to calculate age

```sql
TRUNC((TO_DATE('2022-12-31')-cohort3.BIRTH_DATE)/365.25) AS AGE
```

but I am getting the following error -

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 40 Column: 29
```

The birth_date column in the cohort3 table is of type `VARCHAR` and formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD`

I tried changing `VARCHAR` to date but that still gave errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't stored dates as strings; use a `DATE` data type.

Assuming that `cohort3.BIRTH_DATE` has a `DATE` data type then you want to use `MONTHS_BETWEEN` to calculate the age (as no year has exactly 365.25 days in it so you will introduce errors around birthdays if you use that value but all years have exactly 12 months):

```sql
FLOOR(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, cohort3.BIRTH_DATE)/12) AS age
```

If `BIRTH_DATE` is a string (and you are not changing it) then use `TO_DATE` to convert it to a `DATE`:

```sql
FLOOR(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, TO_DATE(cohort3.BIRTH_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))/12) AS age
```

If you want to get a person's age on a specific day then replace `SYSDATE` with a `DATE` literal, such as `DATE '2022-12-31'`.